# Release Pipeline error when using Azure Dacpac Task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, dacpac

I'm new to using Azure release pipelines and have been fighting issues trying to deploy a database project to a new Azure SQL database.  Currently the pipeline is giving me the following error...

**TargetConnectionString argument cannot be used in conjunction with any other Target database arguments**

I've tried deploying with and without the TargetConnectionString included in my publish profile.  Any suggestions or something else to try?  I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TargetConnectionString`

> Specifies a valid SQL Server/Azure connection string to the target database. If this parameter is specified it shall be used exclusively of all other target parameters. (short form /tcs)

So please remove all other `TargetXXX` arguments.

(if you don't have them can you show what arguments you have inline and in publish profile - of course without data)

Comment: Can you consider upvoting my answer if it was helpful?